# How to use below function in Angular with ElementRef

Tags: jquery, angular

I want to use this jquery function in my angular app.Is there any other way without using Jquery as it is not recommended?

```
 $('multi-item-carousel.carousel-item').each(function(){
      var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

      if (next.next().length>0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      } else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @ViewChild('listInner', {static : false}) CarParaentElement: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;//(carousel-inner)

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    for (let entry of this.CarParaentElement.nativeElement.children) {
    var nextSibling = entry.nextSibling;

    if(!nextSibling || nextSibling === null){
      nextSibling = this.CarParaentElement.nativeElement.children[0];
    }
    var x = nextSibling.firstChild.cloneNode(true);

    this.renderer.appendChild(entry, x);

            for (let i=0;i<2;i++) {
          nextSibling=nextSibling.nextSibling;
        if(!nextSibling || nextSibling === null){
            nextSibling = this.CarParaentElement.nativeElement.children[0];
          }
//          next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      var y =   nextSibling.firstChild.cloneNode(true);

      this.renderer.appendChild(entry,y);
        }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjetcv

Answer (score 0):

As you stated it is not recommended in Angular to do that. Angular renders a template into the DOM, so in order to achieve this don't use ElementRef, as this is a last resort you should do it before the template is rendered using Renderer2: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Parting from here you could start using:

```
let multItemCarousel= this.renderer.selectRootElement('.multi-item-carousel');
```

And using methods such as `appendChild()` or `insertBefore()`

Comment: the answer is using ViewChildren and renderer2 to add/remove classes

Comment: If there is a lot of childs to control, then yes `ViewChildren` will get you the `QueryList` with all the elements